# Challenges to creating and using swap files

Tags: swap

My brother invited me to join his Civ 6 game recently.  An initial diagnosis of my Dell XPS 13 (Ubuntu 18.04) showed I had only 2 gigs however for Steam to use for a swap file.  Whenever I activated the game in Steam, it hung  on the loading data page.. forever!

Having never messed with swap files before I used the excellent [tutorial provided on It's Foss](https://itsfoss.com/create-swap-file-linux/) to get started.  I swapoff the file, and mkswap something larger.  But oh wait, wasn't I supposed to fallocate a new swap file.  Oops!  I just deleted the old swap file (mkswap does that) without adding a new file first!  Suddenly my browser and the toolbar disappear.  In a panic I power down and attempt to reboot - wrong move apparently.  Now I'm stuck at Grub.  Every time I try rebooting the Dell leaves me weeping at the Ubuntu splash screen.

Clearly I need a new swap file simply to reboot, much less run Civ 6.
Additional homework, including:

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Reset_lost_root_password,
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34462/why-does-linux-allow-init-bin-bash,
- https://www.2daygeek.com/shell-script-create-add-extend-swap-space-linux/

helped me patch together something close to a script for accessing BASH through GRUB.  My first run through the Foss process gives notice upon swapon that I just created a four gig file, to whit-
4194300k swap on /swapfile. Priority: -2 extents:29 across : 17580028k SSFS
-looks good huh?
To make sure I'm on the same page I run the Its Foss pipe instructions, thinking this will save the swapfile, and activate it for use.  I reboot, only to find myself once more left crying on the Ubuntu splash page.  I walk back through my process to regain BASH, and free -h returns a swap file, however swapon --show returns nothing.

So what have I done?  Did I actually create a swap file I can use?  If so how have a failed to inform the system to use it?  If not, what pitfalls should I avoid creating a swapfile the second time around?  Help!  I can already hear the settlers and sails of other Civilizations claiming the globe as their own.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you edit /etc/fstab to tell the system about the new swapfile? Swap is not required to boot, but a missing swapfile will cause the system to hang for a couple minutes during boot.

Comment: Boot to Recovery Mode from the GRUB menu, Root Access, then type: `free -h` and `swapon --show` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema I followed your advice, and found the swapfile!    However it still isn't booting.  So I ran fsck and was told I have the wrong count on free blocks.  Fair enough, however Recovery Mode will not then recover on the root system where this is an issue..

Comment: Show me the output of the commands that I requested earlier. Please see my answer. If it's helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**fsck**

To check/repair your file system...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**swap**

To create a 4G /swapfile...

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

Boot to Recovery Mode...

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm ??G RAM and 4G swap
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

Confirm this line in /etc/fstab...

**Note:** Confirm that this is the only line that contains "swap".

```
/swapfile    none    swap    sw      0   0
```

**Update #1:**

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

Comment: I have images showing these steps in recovery mode, but cannot seem to paste through stack exchange to a Comment.  I will walk through the steps using live USB and paste them here tomorrow.  Thanks for your patience!

Comment: @Rogue_417 You can't post images into comments. You'll have to edit your question and add them there.

Comment: #heynnema when I attempt to fsck from the live USB, it cannot find the FS.  So I look in Nautilus.  ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo ls root@major-XPS-13-9360/home
ls: cannot access 'root@major-XPS-13-9360/home': No such file or directory
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo ls root@major-XPS-13-9360 /
ls: cannot access 'root@major-XPS-13-9360': No such file or directory
/:
bin    dev   initrd.img      lib64  opt   root snap  tmp  vmlinuz
boot   etc   initrd.img.old  media  proc  run srv   usr  vmlinuz.old
cdrom  home  lib      mnt    rofs  sbin sys   var

Comment: I find and mount it.  sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mount_point
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ cd /dev/sda2
bash: cd: /dev/sda2: Not a directory
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ls /dev/sda2
/dev/sda2
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ls /dev/sda2/
ls: cannot access '/dev/sda2/': Not a directory
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ls /mount_point
ls: cannot open directory '/mount_point': Permission denied
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo ls /mount_point
bin    dev   initrd.img      lib64  mnt   root  snap      sys  var
boot   etc   initrd.img.old  lost+found  opt   run   srv       tmp  vmlinuz
cdrom  home  lib      media  proc  sbin  swapfile  usr  vmlinuz.old

Comment: Although you can see the swapfile listed, I cannot run free -h to prove the system recognizes it as such.  Again this is all from the live USB. ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo free -h /mount_point/root
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.5G        1.6G        2.2G        833M        3.7G        4.9G
Swap:            0B          0B          0B

Comment: Nor do I seem capable of running fsck on the mount point.  ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fsck -f /mount_point
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
fsck.ext2: Is a directory while trying to open /mount_point

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

Comment: @Rogue_417 `fsck` won't run on a mounted partition. If you follow my instructions exactly, you should be able to do it. Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/UB and then use `fdisk` and then `fsck`.

Comment: I have two disks appearing at fdisk l, labelled sda (Type EFI on 1, Linux filesystem on 2), and sdb (Type Empty on 1, EFI [FAT -12/16/32] on 2).  Running sudo fsck -f on sda2 reveals 1.1% non-continguous blocks, returning no errors.  Running same on sdb2 simply reveals 4 files, 1214/1221 clusters, no errors.

Comment: @Rogue_417 That sounds good. Good job!

Comment: I have two disks appearing at fdisk l, labelled sda (Type EFI on 1, Linux filesystem on 2), and sdb (Type Empty on 1, EFI [FAT -12/16/32] on 2).  Running sudo fsck -f on sda2 reveals 1.1% non-continguous blocks, returning no errors.  Running same on sdb2 simply reveals 4 files, 1214/1221 clusters, no errors.  This from the live USB.  How do I know however fsck isn't simply reporting results of the Live USB and not my old root?  Showing off my ignorance..

Comment: @Rogue_417 sda is your HDD/SSD, and sdb is your USB flash key.

Comment: I shut down the live USB, and start into insecure mode, this time hitting esc to see the reboot unfold.  Numerous failures appear for everything from Network Logging Service, Login Service, Network Manager, Gnome Display Manager, System Logging Service etc.  Each time it starts D-Bus System Message Bus, something stops and something else fails.  Each failure reports a file in systemct1 for details.

Comment: @Rogue_417 Did those errors occur before all this? Boot to the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB again, start `Disks`, and get me screenshots of the SMART Data scrollable window, and lets see if there's a problem with your disk. What is systemct1? Do you mean syslog?

Comment: I ran Parted, fdisk and df - "Disks" command wasn't found. No windows labeled SMART I'm afraid, and as I cannot attach pictures without a better AskUbuntu rep it looks like I'm stuck to theses modest 520 character comments.  :-(

Comment: No... boot to the Ubuntu Live USB, then start the `Disks` app, then find the SMART Data window (at the 3-line "hamburger" menu), then take screenshots. Make sure to scroll the SMART Data window to get all of the data. Take those screenshots and edit them into your original question so I can see them. I need to eliminate a HDD problem.

Comment: I added the Disks screen shots as requested; please see the original post.

Comment: @Rogue_417 Good job on the screenshots. Please see Update #1 in my answer.

Comment: thanks or taking on this challenge!  I will run the memtest, but as it will take hours (and I pay the rent as a cashier..) I probably won't have an answer before Thursday AM.

Comment: I appreciate your patience with my reply.  I attached images of the memtest86 results.  None of the four tests reported back any errors.  Does this eliminate RAM as the issue?  If so does it indicate instead an HDD problem?

Comment: @Rogue_417 Your SSD is fine. Your file system is fine. Your memory is fine. At this point I'd recommend just reinstalling Ubuntu. Report back.

Comment: I haven't a backup install available.  Your recommendation means starting a custom MacBuntu install from scratch.  I will get a second opinion and report back.